# laravel passport login always failed in apps but success but success in postman

Tags: laravel, authentication, client, laravel-passport

Need some help with laravel.

I have this in APIController

```
    public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password
    ];

    if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        $token = auth()->user()->createToken('myToken')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'UnAuthorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

When i login from postman, i got unauthorized.
But when login from apps i failed, it return

> GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException (401)
> Client error: `POST https://api.mydomain.com/api/login` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":"UnAuthorised"}

code that call login

```
    $group = 'all';
    $start_date = $request->start_date;
    $end_date = $request->end_date;

    $date1 = new DateTime($start_date);
    $date2 = new DateTime($end_date);
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    $count_days = $interval->days;

    $health_care = Auth::user()->health_care_id;

    $request->validate([
        'start_date' => 'required',
        'end_date' => 'required',
    ]);
    $client = new Client();
    $token = 'some-token-i-got-from-postman-login-result';
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $cookieJar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();

    $response = $client->post('https://api.mydoman.com/api/login', [
        'form_params' => [
            'email' => 'name@mydoman.com',
            'password' => 'mypassword',
            'action' => 'login',
        ],
        'cookies' => $cookieJar,
    ]);
```

my composer.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
    "laravel/passport": "^8.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

}

I run both front and web API on the same server.

Build on top of laragon(Apache and php 7.2)

Please help

Comment: Can you share some more information on the Postman request which succeeds?

Comment: remove __construct methodfrom your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is environment issue, because my API works well in Live server. So i ended cloning my LIVE API into LIVE DEV-API.
The cause might be because on local i run on windows but on LIVE i run on linux, so i think i need to do some adjustment to make it work on windows.
So the cause still not solved, but at least i know it some environment problem.
Thx you guys for your help and hope this help others

other solution:
run with "php artisan serve" instead using webserver

Answer (score 0):

use `json` instead of `form_params`:

```
'json' => [
            'email' => 'name@mydoman.com',
            'password' => 'mypassword',
            'action' => 'login',
        ]
```

Comment: still unauthorized, any other idea?

Comment: what is `dd($request->all())`  result?

Comment: where do i put this dd? at API or Frontend ?

Comment: in login method before `if` statment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot the headers in the api's poster, you should do:

```
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
```

if you are using a next js and communicating it with a laravel